# Get number of hit on a SharePoint 2013 blog

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Is there a way, I can retrieve the number of hits on a blog post in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Web Analytics. That will give you numbers very easily.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2014/01/28/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2013/08/31/sharepoint-2013-web-analytics-report-where-is-it.aspx

For the identity of users you could try using auditing, that will let you see who's accessing the site. Other than auditing you'd need to look at custom code of some sort that runs when a web-part is rendered.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx